# I need to provide details of my AWS EC2 Instance via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I need give server access to someone to help debug my code.

Can someone please explain what/where I can find the SSH Credentials. I am new to all of this so apologizes....

Comment: When EC2 instance was created a key pair is associated with it usually. You can provide that key for SSH access to your EC2 instance OR you can follow instructions - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/

Answer (score 0):

If you've lost your SSH key, you can now also use the Systems Manager Sessions Manager:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html